# Hasselblad H cameras. How does the viewfinder image correspondent with the photograph?

Tags: viewfinder, hasselblad

The Hasselblad H cameras are modular. There are different digital backs for each camera available which actually feature different sensor sizes.

How does the image in the viewfinder correspondent to the image that the sensor will take? With different sensor sizes the image wont be the same.

My Nikon fullframe DSLR masks the viewfinder when it is set to APS-C mode so I know what the image will look like. How does a Hasselblad H cameras viewfinder show me what image Im about to take?

Answer (score 2):

The viewfinder is modular as well; they offer different ones for the different sensor sizes.

Comment: Would you mind to go into a little bit more detail about which viewfinder is designed for which sensor?

Answer (score 2):

The H viewfinder contains a focussing screen that can be easily changed for the different sensor sizes.

[H System focusing screens](https://store.hasselblad.com/t/h6-system-category/focusing-screens)